# CQRS/ES for a user management microservice

Tags: cqrs, users, event-sourcing

I'm fairly new to CQRS and Event Sourcing, though I have built one application (ASP.NET MVC) that uses it for a part of its business domain (one "bounded context" if you will).

So I know how to implement it, and I've seen the benefits.

In the near future, I will need to create a new application that is solely focussed on user management. This is part of a larger group of microservices, where each has its responsibility.

This user management service will be an application where users can manage their account (name, password, etc), billing (upgrade to certain tiers of our services), etc. It will most likely also be used as an SSO provider for our different applications. Other possibilities in the future could be to have it be a provider of widgets (like a sign-on widget) for various web applications.

I was wondering if CQRS and ES are a good match for this. User management typically sounds like just CRUD stuff. But I've seen the benefits and elegance that can come from CQRS/ES.

On the other hand, I'm afraid I'm looking at this in a biased way because CQRS/ES is now my new golden hammer. As mentioned above, I actually only have experience with CQRS/ES on one project.

I read somewhere CQRS/ES shouldn't be applied on every part of your application/domain, but it makes sense on the core of your application. For this user management micro service, the user management *is* the core.

Any ideas or suggestions on how I can decide whether or nog CQRS/ES is a good route to take?

Comment: Why don't you try building a couple of small prototypes using CQRS and ES, and see where it takes you?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a match.

User profile info is usually only edited by the one owning user itself.

As such the user info can easily be sharded and the profile editing scaled out, which has to be simpler than a CQRS+ES alternative.